# Javascript IIFE Immediately invoked function Expression

Tags: javascript

I have created function expression in JavaScript:

```
var MKObjects = MKObjects || {};

MKObjects.spReporting = (function () {
    // methods
})();
```

and it works fine -- the problem is: how do I find it in the console window?

It wasn't created in the global namespace -- it's not defined on the window object apparently.

When I type in `MKObjects` or `MKObjects.spReporting` in console window, I get nothing.

Comment: If `MKObjects` is not global then you cannot access it from global scope. That has nothing to do with IIFEs. You can make it global explicitly by doing `window.MKObjects = MKObjects;`, if that's what you want.

Comment: "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: @Quentin: I think it's just a typo in the question: `(()` -> `)()`.

Comment: @FelixKling — Well, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to debug it, you can place a breakpoint immediately after the assignment when the debugger is still in the same scope.

Otherwise, if `MKObjects` is not a global and not accessible from a global (i.e. field in a global var) then you won't be able to access it from the console.

For example:

```
(function() {
  var x = ...;
})()
```

You are unable to access `x` in the debugger because it is not visible from the global scope.

```
var x;
(function() {
  x = ...;
})()
```

You are able to access `x` because it's global.

```
var y;
(function() {
  var x = ...;
  y.propertyX = x;
})()
```

You are able to access `x` through the `y` global by `y.propertyX`

```
(function() {
  var x = ...;
  debugger; // or breakpoint
})()
```

You will have temporary access to `x` from the debugger window when code execution reaches this point.

The fact that your assignment is the result of an anonymous immediately invoked function is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you I was able to set the breakpoint and get what I needed-

 Is this a good strategy In terms of not polluting the global namespace ?

 Seems like it may be ok in my situation and I am able to return just the    methods I want public-

Comment: Yes. That sounds like a good plan. You should avoid polluting global namespace and if the only reason to "see" this variable is for debugging, then you can use debugger statements/breakpoints.  If this answer solves your problem, please accept (checkmark) and/or upvote (arrow) to mark as resolved/helpful.